# Concatenate 2 values from the same column with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to concatenate 2 values from the same column but with different conditions. here is my sample table.

```
 ----------------------------------
| user_id | key        | value     |
 ----------------------------------
  1         firstname    maria
  1         lastname     enuole
  2         firstname    chris
  2         lastname     magnolia
```

concatenating values from the value field with key firstname and lastname with the same user_id. Sorry its really hard to explain.

i would like a result like this...

```
 --------------------------
| user_id | Name           |
 --------------------------
  1         maria enuole
  2         chris magnolia
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using `Conditional Aggregate` but I prefer `Group_concat` approach

```
select user_id, concat(F_name, ' ', L_name)
From
(
select user_id, 
       max(case when key = 'firstname' then value end) F_name,
       max(case when key = 'lastname' then value end) as L_name
From Yourtable
Group by user_id
) A
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `group_concat()` and `order by`.  In your case, the solution is pretty simple:

```
select user_id,
       group_concat(value separator ' ' order by key) as name
from t
where key in ('firstname', 'lastname')
group by user_id;
```

Or, use the `join` approach:

```
select tfirst.user_id, concat_ws(' ', tfirst.value, tlast.value) as name
from t tfirst join
     t tlast
     on tfirst.user_id = tlast.user_id and
        tfirst.key = 'firstname' and
        tlast.key = 'lastname';
```

Comment: `WHERE key IN ('firstname', 'lastname')` It is clearly `EAV` table and I bet there are also other keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT user_id
     , GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ' ') as Name 
  FROM tablename 
 GROUP BY user_id
```